# When is the data in a spark partition actually realised?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am analysing the performance of my spark application in case of small datasets. I have a lineage graph which looks something like following:

```
someList.toDS()
.repartition(x)
.mapPartitions(func1)
.mapPartitions(func2)
.mapPartitions(func3)
.filter(cond1)
.count()
```

I have a cluster of 2 nodes with 8 cores on each. Executors are configured to use 4 cores. So, when the application is running four executors come up using 4 cores each.

I am observing at least (and usually only) 1 task on each thread (i.e. 16 tasks in total) takes a lot longer than other tasks. For example, in one run these tasks are taking approx 15-20 seconds, compared to other tasks running in a second or less.

On profiling the code, I found the bottleneck to be in func3 above:

```
def func3 = (partition: Iterator[DomainObject]) => {
  val l = partition.toList          // This takes almost all of the time
  val t = doSomething(l)
}
```

The conversion from an Iterator to a List takes up almost all of the time.

The partition size is very small (even less than 50 in some cases). Even then, the size of partition is almost consistent across different partitions, but only one task per thread takes up the time.

I would have assumed that by the time `func3` runs on the executor for a task, the data within that partition would already be present on the executor. Is this not the case? (Does it iterate over the entire dataset to filter out data for this partition somehow, during the execution of func3?!)

Else, why should the conversion from an `Iterator` over less than fifty objects to a `List` take up that much time?

Other thing I note (not sure if that is relevant) is the GC time (as per spark ui) for these tasks is also unusually consistent 2s for all of these sixteen tasks, as compared to other tasks (even then, 2s<<20s)

Update:
Following is how the event timeline looks for the four executors:
[image: spark ui : event timeline for the stage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the data in the partition is available as soon as the task starts executing (or, at least there is not any significant cost in iterating through that data, as the question would make it seem.)

The bottleneck in above code is actually in func2 (which I did not investigate properly!), and is because of the lazy nature of the iterators in scala. The problem is not related to spark at all.

Firstly, the functions in the mapPartitions calls above *appear* to get chained and called like so: `func3( func2( func1(Iterator[A]) ) ) : Iterator[B]`. So the `Iterator` produced as output of `func2` is fed to `func3` directly.

Secondly, for above issue `func1` (and `func2`) are defined as :

```
func1(x: Iterator[A]) => Iterator[B] = x.map(...).filter...
```

Since these take an iterator and map them to a different iterator, these are not executed right away. But when `func3` is executed, `partition.toList` causes to map closure in `func2` to get executed. On profiling, it appears that `func3` took all the time, where instead `func2` has the code slowing the application.

(Specific to above problem, `func2` contains some serialising of case objects to a json string. It appears to execute some time-consuming implicit code, only for the first object on each thread. Since it happens once for each thread, each thread has just one task which takes very long, and explains the event timeline above.)

Answer (score 1):

1. First realization is during `repartition()`
2. Second is after the `filter` operation, where all the three `mapPartitions` starts execution (when the `count` action is called). Depending on your `doSomething()` in each of those functions it will depend how the DAG will be created and where it is taking time and accordingly you can optimize.

Comment: Why is materialisation happening in ```filter```? How is ```filter``` different from other transformations? Also, can you provide some more info on how the DAG is dependent upon the functions passed to mapPartitions?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to mean after the `filter` operation, i detailed it out in point 2. The DAG is usually formed based on the three functions you have, it checks which dataset is re-used, or how it is re-used in each of the functions, may be an intermediate dataset from the 1st function can be reused in the second and third, acoordingly the DAG is formed. I tried to explain it vaguely, but without seeing the functions its pretty hard to explain how to imporve the execution.

Comment: "it checks which dataset is re-used" -- So, all the functions are closures of the form ```(it: Iterator[SomeDomainObject]) => Iterator[AnotherDomainObject]```, and internally transform the object based on some business logic (involving some I/O and other stuff). In any case, the internals are oblivious to spark. I do not understand : "... which dataset is re-used.." : there is just one dataset, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the ds is split to different partitions, and shuffled. The operations on those partitions are optimized by spark.

Comment: Hi.. yes, you are right : ds is partitioned and shuffled. However, in the above lineage, after the repartition happens, the mapPartitions do not require shuffling (and hence all are part of one job). Once a partition is materialised on an executor, the operations would be optimised by spark, but it should not involve any shuffling writes (except writing the count, which is the action in this case). I found the bottleneck which was slowing down the tasks, and its not related to spark. I shall update details in an answer. (Thank you for your time!)